# No resource identifier found for attribute 'fullBackupContent' in package 'android'

Tags: android, eclipse

part of my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeCompat"
        android:largeHeap="true" >
```

I'm newbie in android developer, i use eclipse mars with sdk 25.1.3 and i get this error. they are no '/xml' folder under 'res/' in my project.
what should i do to fix this issue?

sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Does your manifest tag look like this?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        package="com.my.appexample">
```

I never used "fullBackupContent" but every attribute needs to be declared with the xmlns to use it.

Also, if you say you are new to android development. Why do you need "fullBackupContent" and "largeHeap"? Did you copy that from somewhere or is it on purpose?

Comment: not all same, this my manifest tag look like; '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; package="my.company" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="@string/app_version_name">' I got existing project from my new company vendor, so a have new assign to learn android from my boss. thx before

Comment: Hm what is the ";" (between xmlns:android and package-tag) doing there? Please remove it and test again.